# Facebook c# sdk - can i share a post on my wall using Post_id from added by API before?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

i use Facebook c# sdk to post image to my Page result return Post_id

> var result = (IDictionary)app.Post("/PageId /photos", parameters);

can i share this post using post_ID on my wall ?

> app.post(result.Post_id +"/feed");

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to share Image Using

> app.Post("me/feed", new Dictionary { { "link", link } });

facebook Photo Link :

> string link = "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=" + result.id;